# Simple Shadertoy to regular glsl

Tags: opengl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I want the code in glslSandBox to a regular glsl. Suppose I have a quad mesh 3D displaced in a 3D scene. I want to create this "shadertoy-like" texture and apply to it. I'm aware about the transformations it requires : Screen - NDC - CLIPSPACE - WORLDSPACE, but still I'm struggling. http://glslsandbox.com/e#61091.0 this is an extremely simple shader, can you please demonstrate the normal vs and fs shader it would take to apply it to a 3D mesh in a 3D scene?

Answer (score 0):

The shader you linked is a fragment shader drawing on a flat screen plane.

Typically, the corresponding vertex setup would be two triangles (potentially as a strip, meaning 4 vertices in total), covering the entire screen. In fact, you don't really have to be concerning yourself with any transformations, especially given that the fs uses `gl_FragCoord` and the resolution is being passed as a uniform.

VS:

```
#version 450
in vec4 position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = position
}
```

Vertices (example, use with `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`):

```
-1, -1
-1,  1
 1, -1
 1,  1
```

After you cover the entire screen, you can now just switch this setup to render to texture; create a framebuffer, attach a texture to it, and render in the same way. Then you'll be able to use that texture on your 3D model. This will work well if the generated image rarely changes.

If you actually wanted to draw that in one pass, then you'll need to pass the texture coordinate as a varying variable, and use it instead of `gl_FragCoord`; no other changes should be necessary.